# Question sorting by votes is broken

Tags: bug, questions, lists

When sorting the Questions page by [votes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=votes) (and 50 per page), a lot of questions are left out so that the last question on the first page has a score of -11.

EDIT: Now there's a problem on the bottom of [page 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=votes):

[image]

Wait, clicking on page 2 again and the problem is gone...

Comment: It looks to me like it's fixed now... which is weird, because I can absolutely confirm it _was_ broken just a moment ago.

Comment: @Emrakul I still see the problem on page 2.

Comment: Huh! That's weird. I don't see it. Can you maybe add a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: I see this too.